# Blueborne patch for Kitkat

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have an embedded device running Android Kitkat 4.4.4 and due to specific reasons, I cannot upgrade this to later versions of Android.

I'd like to patch this device for the Blueborne vulnerability and though the security update on the [AOSP site](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2017-09-01) lists 4.4.4 as patched, they don't provide a link to the commit/reference for the patch. The vulnerabilities are:

- CVE-2017-0781
- CVE-2017-0782
- CVE-2017-0783
- CVE-2017-0784
- CVE-2017-0785

There are patches for later versions under /system/bt, but this code branch does not exist on 4.4.4; The bluedroid stack on the latest revision tag of 4.4.4 (i.e. [android-4.4.4_r2.0.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1)) has not seen any updates in a while (and is fairly different from the more mature stack available in recent versions of Android).

How do I patch my 4.4.4 device with the right security fixes to prevent attacks?